# Wordpress Custom Fields work with Translation

Tags: php, wordpress, function, field, translation

This seems like it should be easy, but I seem to have trouble getting it to work.

I have a Wordpress site using qtranslatex and I want to be able to use the language switching tabs in the Custom Fields section.  Qtranslatex has a setting to enter an element 'id' or 'class'.  That is fine for the 'Value' field in the 'Add New Custom Field', it has a simple 'id' that can be used.  If there are custom field values already entered, there is the problem.  Wordpress creates a new 'id' for each 'Value' field for each page, thereby making it impossible to list all the 'id's that get created.

I checked out the element and Wordpress currently does not add a 'class' to the Custom Field 'Value' textarea.

All I want to do is an add_action() or add_filter() in my functions.php file to modify the function located in template.php called '_list_meta_row' that generates the HMTL for the Custom Field 'Value' textarea.  Just want to stick a "class='custom-field-value'" into the HTML.

Please help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was not exactly the kind of answer I was looking for, but I figured out a basic solution using jQuery.  I was hoping to just do something in php.

I created this jQuery function that adds a 'class' to each of the Custom Field Value  elements.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('[id^="meta-"][id$="-value"]').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('custom-field-value');
    });

});
```

Now in the qTranslateX settings under the Integration tab there is a place to set a id or class for Custom Fields.  So, I just set the class setting to 'custom-field-value' as it shows in my script above.